# Как с помощью Beautiful soup найти все ссылки на файлы xlsx?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, re

Существует сайт из которого нужно скопировать все ссылки на файлы формата .xlsx

```py
import requests
URL = 'https://rosstat.gov.ru/vpn_popul'
resp = requests.get(URL)
html = resp.text

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
myhtml = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')

myTags = myhtml.find_all('/.xlsx)
myTags
```

Питон выдает пустой список, то есть ничего не находит

Comment: На данной странице таких ссылок нет.

Comment: На сайте нашел только rar архивы с таблицами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myTags = myhtml.find_all('a', href=lambda x: 
x and x.endswith('.xlsx'))
```

или регулярка:

```
import re
myTags = myhtml.find_all('a', href=re.compile('.*\.xlsx$'))
```

Ещё вариант - библиотека `lxml`:

```
from lxml import html
myhtml = html.fromstring(resp.content)
myTags = myhtml.xpath('//a[ends-with(@href,".xlsx")]')
```

Или примени модуль `re` или `regex`:

```
import re
links = re.findall(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+\.xlsx', html)
```

Comment: Интересно, а вы нашли, с помощью хотя бы одного вашего метода, хотя бы одну ссылку на файл .xlsx на данной странице?